# MVVM Design Pattern for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I am writing a Windows Phone application and planned to use some MVVM idea in it. 
I know that with command binding I can easily separate UI and logic, but the problem is I don't know how I can get access to the controls properties, for example:

I have a map control on the main page, for which I want to show a push pin at the place user taps at. But with MVVM I don't think there is anyway I can do that. Means I can not access to the maps properties and methods to do things like that, is it right?

If anyone has experience with MVVM please share your idea about how to use control's properties and methods to perform tasks.

(P.S. I dont want to use MVVM Light or any toolkit for this application)

Thank you

Comment: Surely you would just bind the data on the model to the map? The map must expose some property for allowing pins to be added - I assume it has databinding support? I'd say that all decent Silverlight controls do...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do - binding a to a property which determines where to show a pin on the map - is a pretty specific use case, which is why the map control does not expose a property for this.

If you want to follow the MVVM pattern I would recommend creating a user control / custom control that wraps the map control and exposes a dependency property to which you can bind to. When this property is changed you check if there's a pin added to the map and if not, add one; otherwise move it to the correct position.

Bottom line is you'll need to create some custom control and expose the property/properties to bind to if you want to implement the solution following the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Hi, I went and searched through the internet, but did not see any example about the implementation of your answer. If you have any reference or suggest website that have some sample code, it would be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: Creating a custom control isn't strictly necessary, the same thing can be accomplished with an custom attached property on an existing map control.